# textAngular.js with requireJS gives saveSelection error after change

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, textangular

Does anyone able to get textAngular.js with RequireJS(even if someone has working example I will replicate the settings)?

I am able to load editor but when applying h1 tags I get 
$window.rangy.saveSelection is not a function on textAngular.js file with                   _savedSelection = $window.rangy.saveSelection();

Here are versions I am using.

Angular 1.4.8
textAngular 1.4.6
Rangy 1.3.1-dev
RequireJS 2.1.22

Answer (score 2):

The issue is textAngular in its core, expects a variable `rangy` to be available globally (https://github.com/aaronroberson/textAngular/blob/master/src/main.js#L69).

So to fix this problem, we combined the rangy-core and rangy-selectionsaverestore into our `window.rangy` at the beginning of the bootstrap of our application before we initialise the app with `angular.module('appname', [modules...])`

`define(["angular", "ngRoute", "jquery", "rangy-core", "rangy-selectionsaverestore"], function(angular, ngRoute, $j, rangyCore, rangySelectionSavereStore) {
  window.rangy = $j.extend(rangyCore, rangySelectionSavereStore);
});`

Configuration for requirejs to load these two modules,

`'rangy-core': '../bower_components/rangy/rangy-core',
'rangy-selectionsaverestore': '../bower_components/rangy/rangy-selectionsaverestore'`